# Implicit differentiation derivative not as expected

Tags: calculus, derivatives, implicit-differentiation

I am trying to solve the problem: $x^{2}+xy+y^{3}=0$ using implicit differentiation.

My workings:

$(1)\,\,\,{d\over dx}{[x^2]}\,+{d\over dx}{[xy]}\,+\,{d\over dx}{[y^3]}={d\over dx}{[0]}$

$(2)\,\,\,2x+y+{{dy^3}\over{dy}}{{dy}\over{dx}}=0$

$(3)\,\,\,2x+y+3y^2\,({dy\over dx})=0$

$(4)\,\,\,{dy\over dx}=\boxed{-{{2x+y}\over{3y^2}}}$

But the answer says it should be:

$(3)\,\,\,2x+y+{{dxy}\over{dy}}{{dy}\over{dx}} + 3y^2\,({dy\over dx})=0$

$(4)\,\,\,2x+y+{dy\over dx}(x+3y^2)=0$

$(5)\,\,\,{dy\over dx}=-{2x\,+\,y\over{x\,+\,3y^2}}$

Why?

Comment: So $\cfrac{d}{dx}(xy)= xy'(x)+y(x)$, by product rule.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't conclude that $\frac{d}{dx}(xy)=y$, since this is effectively the product of the functions $x$ and $y$. Hence, using the product rule gives
$$\frac{d}{dx}(xy)=y\frac{d}{dx}(x)+x\frac{d}{dx}(y)=y+x\frac{dy}{dx}$$
The rest should work out as expected.

*edited to reflect Vegeta's comment*

Comment: You forgot an $x$, the r.h.s. should be :$y + x\cfrac{dy}{dx}$

Answer (score 1):

Differentials will make the process much more intuitive.
$$\eqalign{
&0 = d\Big(x^2 + xy + y^3\Big) \\
&0 = 2x\,dx + \big(x\,dy+y\,dx\big) + 3y^2dy \\
&\big(x+3y^2\big)\,dy = -\big(2x+y\big)\,dx \\
&\frac{dy}{dx} = -\left(\frac{2x+y}{x+3y^2}\right) \\
}$$